# Google Maps API Geocoding <> Static Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been getting "ZERO_RESULTS" for the following address when I try to get the latitude and longitude for it but it shows up OK in the static map request below. Does anyone know why? (It has been working OK for other addresses generally.)

### Geocode URL

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Bali+Zoo+Jl.+Raya+Singapadu+Banjar+Seseh+Sukawati+Batuan+Sukawat%2c+Singapadu%2c+Sukawati%2c+Kabupaten%2c+Gianyar+-%2c+Bali%2c+Indonesia&sensor=false

### Response:

ZERO_RESULTS

### Static Map URL

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Bali+Zoo+Jl.+Raya+Singapadu+Banjar+Seseh+Sukawati+Batuan+Sukawat%2c+Singapadu%2c+Sukawati%2c+Kabupaten%2c+Gianyar+-%2c+Bali%2c+Indonesia&zoom=16&scale=2&size=300x160&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:blue%7Clabel:%7CBali+Zoo+Jl.+Raya+Singapadu+Banjar+Seseh+Sukawati+Batuan+Sukawat%2c+Singapadu%2c+Sukawati%2c+Kabupaten%2c+Gianyar+-%2c+Bali%2c+Indonesia

### Static Map Response:

[image: Map]

Comment: That looks like a "place" to me, the Places API should be able to resolve it.  [place API request](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Bali+Zoo+Indonesia&place=1) (your "address" is way over specified as well).  The Geocoding API is for postal addresses, not places.

Comment: Strange because even the Places API gives the address as "Jl. Raya Singapadu Banjar Seseh Sukawati Batuan Sukawati Gianyar Bali, Singapadu, Sukawati, Kabupaten Gianyar, Bali 80582, Indonesia (-8.5915798, 115.26561730000003)" at the bottom of your page. I suppose the best method would be to try for http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode first and if that doesn't return a result then use the organization name, state and country second with the Places API? I'm not sure whether every address (e.g. a not so significant business) would be a place?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices

Comment: Thanks. That was a helpful comment. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment by geocodezip, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices was helpful.